# Azure Service Bus - Message Count in JAVA

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How could i get the total number of unprocessed message count from Azure Service bus using JAVA. Is there any API that can show the total number of message that is yet to be processed.

Is there any equivalent to the below .Net library in JAVA  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.messagecount?view=azure-dotnet)

.Net Namespace: Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging

Whats the equlant for the above .Net Namespace in JAVA?

Comment: Please edit your question and include some code. Show us what you have tried so far and the issues you're running into.

Comment: With respect to code, there are no API's that i could find in the internet. The question is all about is there any API that can give me the number of message in the service bus using JAVA! @GauravMantri

Comment: @JayGong found the Java SDK for Service Bus. Please see his answer below.

Comment: @Rasmi You could mark my answer if you think my answer helps you.That could for others' references, thanks a lot Rasmi.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any API that can give me the number of message in the service
>   bus using JAVA?

You could refer to [Message counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-counters) doc. You could use `MessageCountDetails` [Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.messagecountdetails) to get `ActiveMessageCount` property.

Which is equivalent to the .NET library `MessageCount` in java: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus._queue.messagecount

Comment: the class Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging is not available in JAVA

Comment: @Rasmi Don't know what you want. The ActiveMessageCount shows the number of the pending messages, does it?

Comment: @Rasmi You're welcome.Please mark it for others' reference on the forum.Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are Java classes available for management of the Service Bus and I think the one you're looking for is [MessageCountDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.messagecountdetails?view=azure-java-stable). There are examples of how to use the management classes in [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-java-manage-queue-with-advanced-features/blob/f78d39ab595699b400aa94a976b8239d5d617b71/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/servicebus/samples/ServiceBusQueueAdvanceFeatures.java). Currently that uses version 0.9.7 of the Azure Service Bus libraries, but same classes seem to exist in the latest 2.0.0-PREVIEW-7.